# Probability that a random variable is k-th when ordered - simplification needed.

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics, nonparametric

My first post... I'm trying to simplify the following problem:

Let $F_e(x)$ be a continuous cdf of some distribution parametrised by $e$. Let us assume that:

(a) The mean of this distribution increases in $e$,

(b) Its variance decreases in $e$.

Suppose that we consider $n$ random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ whose distributions are characterised by the cdfs $F_{e_1}, F_{e_2} \dots F_{e_n}$. Suppose now that we want to know what are the odds of the variable $X_1$ to have the k-highest realisation of the $n$ random variables. I believe the probability of that would be:

$Prob(X_1 \text{ is k-th highest} ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{K \in A} \left(  \prod_{i \in K} F_{e_i}(y) \prod_{i \in K'} (1 - F_{e_i}(y)) \right)dF_{e_1}(y)  $

where $A$ is the set of collections of indices such that: $A = \{ K:|K| = n-k \}$ and $K' = A\backslash(K\cup \{1\} )$ so $|K'| = k-1$.

For simplicity, we may consider $e_2 = e_3 = \dots = e_n = e^*$ to get:

$Prob(X_1 \text{ is k-th highest} ) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {{n-1}\choose{k-1}} F_{e^*}^{n-k}(y) (1 - F_{e^*}(y))^{k-1} dF_{e_1}(y)$

I am looking for a distribution that satisfies (a), (b) and for which the probabilities above simplify. In particular, I would like to get rid of the integrals with respect to $y$, and hopefully make the terms easy to differentiate with respect to $e_1$.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No, this is not related to any coursework. I'm in the process of writing a model of a particular kind of a contest, and I'm looking for ways to make it tractable.